# $P(V\gt 1)$ given $U\sim \operatorname{unif}(0,1)$, $X\sim \operatorname{expo}(1)$, $V=U+X$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Consider independent random variables $U$ and $X$, where $U$ is
>   uniformly distributed on the interval $(0,1)$, and $X$ is an
>   exponential random variable having mean $1$. Letting $V=U+X$, give the
>   value of $P(V >1)$.

I have that $$P(V\gt 1)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(V\gt 1 | U=u)\cdot f_U(u)du$$

$$\begin{align*}
P(V\gt 1 | U=u)
&=P(X\gt1-u)\\\\
&=1-P(X\leq 1-u)\\\\
&=1-F_X(1-u)\\\\
&=1-\left(1-e^{-(1-u)}\right)\\\\
&= e^{-(1-u)}\\\\
\end{align*}$$

Thus I get

$$P(V\gt 1)=\int_0^1 e^{-(1-u)}du=\frac{e-1}{e} \approx0.632$$

Is this correct? I would also be interested in seeing alternative solutions if there is a more efficient method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks fine.

You might want to mention that $u \in [0,1]$ as you compute $P(V > 1|U=u)$.